# Strange behave of the tagging system/perhaps user-account mismatch in SE

Tags: support, user-accounts, specific-user, multiple-accounts

If I access the question "divergent product" ([Divergent products.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125906/divergent-products)) using the tag [gamma-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamma-function) or using the tag [divergent-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divergent-series) I see the same name for the author of the question  ("gerben") but one time with 16 rep and one time with 1 rep. Perhaps the unexperienced user has one correct account under his name, and has also stepped in without registration but with the same symbolic name, don't know.
Anyway, the SE-engine seems to step between that user-accounts(?) arbitrarily when you click on the user-names.

Is someone able to look at this? (I didn't want to make a big thing out of this so I did not apply the option of flagging)

Answer (score 3):

The question was asked by an unregistered user, and the account seems to have "split" (and a second account was created).

The original question was asked by a user account with 16 points; then answered by a *different user account* (which likely belongs to the same user) and it only has 1 point.

If you look closely you'll see that the case of 16 points it says "asked by ..." and in the case of the 1 point it says "answered by ..."

Comment: Perhaps someone can contact the user and help him merge his regular account and his ad-hoc-/temporary account? I remember I had also to merge two accounts when I began accessing MO but it's long time ago and I don't remember how this worked... (and, surely, I cannot contact the user myself) (and, to help that user was also the original intention of my question)

Answer (score 2):

This *might* explain the differences you are seeing. Note that when you view a [random](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) tag [by newest](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random?sort=newest) the questions are sorted according to asking time, and the account shown will be the account used to ask the question. Looking at it [by activity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random?sort=active) shows the questions sorted by last activity time, and the account shown will be that which last made an action (*e.g.*, posting or editing a post) in the question.

As Asaf mentioned, one [Gerben](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/211670/gerben) account was used to ask the question, and another [Gerben](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/214149/gerben) had the last activity in the question. (The asking account is unregistered, and has likely been lost to the owner.)